# generic type inside parameter

Tags: java, generics

i have the following:

```
public <T extends Node> T create(Class<T> classType, String id, Transaction t){
    T obj;
    try {
        NodeKey nodeKey = new NodeKey(classType, id);
        obj = classType.getConstructor(NodeKey.class, Transaction.class).newInstance(nodeKey, t);
        add(obj, t);
        return obj;
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

has you can see, i "build" `NodeKey nodeKey = new NodeKey(classType, id);`; I want to be able to overload the above method accepting just `NodeKey` and `Transaction`, but the i don't know how can i tell to generics that the T type is the Class returned by a method like `nodeKey.getUserType()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to add a generic parameter to `NodeKey`? So, `NodeKey<T> nodeKey = new NodeKey<T>(classType, id);`. (As ever, I suggest avoiding reflection.)

Answer (score 1):

If NodeKey isn't parametrized itself, it's not possible for any of its methods to explicitly name the type. You have to find a way around it using unsafe casts.

Comment: you are right, i can parametrize NodeKey!
If you edit with a quick example of NodeKey i'll accept your answer